# How to make different text for each button?

Tags: javascript

How to make different text for each button?

A block consists of a background image and buttons placed on top of the image.

The text inside the buttons is arbitrary.

Functional:

- When you click on each button, it “opens” to display the signature
- Clicking on an open button or image again closes the open button.

```js
function changeTextAndSize(circle) {
  circle.classList.toggle('active');
  if (circle.classList.contains('active')) {
    circle.style.transform = 'scale(1.1)';
    circle.innerText = '-  Стадион';
  } else {
    circle.innerText = '+';
  }
}

const listCircle = document.querySelectorAll('.circle')

listCircle.forEach(circle => {
  circle.addEventListener("click", () => changeTextAndSize(circle));
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cir-1 {
  background: rgb(153 255 153 / 0.7);
  margin-left: 592px;
  margin-top: 435px;
}

.cir-2 {
  background: rgb(153 255 153 / 0.7);
  margin-left: 1000px;
  margin-top: 363px;
}

.cir-3 {
  background: rgb(153 255 153 / 0.7);
  margin-left: 1148px;
  margin-top: 597px;
}

.cir-4 {
  background: rgb(153 255 153 / 0.7);
  margin-left: 960px;
  margin-top: 709px;
}

.cir-5 {
  background: rgba(26, 1, 255, 0.7);
  margin-left: 508px;
  margin-top: 256px;
}

.cir-6 {
  background: rgba(26, 1, 255, 0.7);
  margin-left: 390px;
  margin-top: 640px;
}

.cir-7 {
  background: rgba(26, 1, 255, 0.7);
  margin-left: 944px;
  margin-top: 567px;
}

.cir-8 {
  background: rgba(26, 1, 255, 0.7);
  margin-left: 1236px;
  margin-top: 433px;
}

.cir-9 {
  background: rgba(26, 1, 255, 0.7);
  margin-left: 1380px;
  margin-top: 636px;
}

.cir-10 {
  background: rgba(26, 1, 255, 0.7);
  margin-left: 1197px;
  margin-top: 204px;
}

.circle::after {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.circle {
  height: 27px;
  width: 27px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.circle:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.circle.active {
  width: max-content;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="../img/stadium.jpg" alt="Стадион">
</div>
<div id="div">
  <button class="circle  cir-1" id="cir-1">+</button>
  <button class="circle cir-2" id="cir-2">+</button>
  <button class="circle cir-3" id="cir-3">+</button>
  <button class="circle cir-4" id="cir-4">+</button>
  <button class="circle cir-5" id="cir-5">+</button>
  <button class="circle cir-6" id="cir-6">+</button>
  <button class="circle cir-7" id="cir-7">+</button>
  <button class="circle cir-8" id="cir-8">+</button>
  <button class="circle cir-9" id="cir-9">+</button>
  <button class="circle cir-10" id="cir-10">+</button>
</div>
```

Here code: https://codepen.io/OlgaVishneva/pen/abPYyMM

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: Is this? Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Likely OP wants variable text for `circle.innerText`. And thus how to do so efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `id` of the `button.circle` element:

```js
function changeTextAndSize(circle) {
  circle.classList.toggle('active');
  if (circle.classList.contains('active')) {
    circle.style.transform = 'scale(1.1)';
    circle.innerText = `- ${circle.id}`; // <!-- Here
  } else {
    circle.innerText = '+';
  }
}
```

If you assign a `title`:

```html
<button class="circle" id="cir-1" title="Circle 1">+</button>
```

```js
circle.innerText = `- ${circle.getAttribute('title')}`; // <!-- Here
```

Or you could use a data attribute e.g. `data-text`.

```html
<button class="circle" id="cir-1" data-text="Circle 1">+</button>
```

```js
circle.innerText = `- ${circle.dataset.text)}`; // <!-- Here
```

Also, having a class called `cir-1` on the button is pointless. It is already a `.circle` and has an id of `#cir-1`.

Comment: please tell me how to make sure that when the screen is reduced to 1280px, the buttons remain in place?

Comment: @Olga instead of using `margin-*`, use `top` and `left` to position elements. The buttons need `absolute` positioning and the `div#div` element needs `relative` positioning.